# How to check what annotations are included by other annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

We know that there are annotations that include automatically other annotations.
Can you tell me how to check if `@EnableAutoConfiguration` include (it means adds under hood) `@EnableTransactionManagement`

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this :

```
 ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                    new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
            scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(EnableAutoConfiguration.class));
                for(BeanDefinition bean:scanner.findCandidateComponents("PACKAGES TO SCAN")){

                Class<?> aClass=Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName()); 
`// you can also use aClass.getAnnotatedInterfaces() to find the other` annotations     
                if(aClass != null && aClass.isAnnotationPresent(EnableTransactionManagement.class)){
                    System.out.println(" Found "+aClass.getName());                         
                }       
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot can give you a list of all the beans that it created along with some information about why it chose to include/exclude them. Just set the property `debug=true` and watch the logged output on startup. This is demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sw7I70vjN0E&list=WL&t=615

I don't know if it will specifically print out the `@Enable...` annotations, but those annotations generally just provide an `@Import` annotation to some configuration. Looking the source of `@EnableTransactionManagement`, I see this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector.class)
public @interface EnableTransactionManagement {
```

If you use the debug property, Spring will definitely print out whether or not it created a `TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector` bean, which should tell you whether or not `@EnableTransactionManagement` was used in your application.

Comment: It's in the documentation, but it's shockingly difficult to find considering how often one needs to reference it.

Comment: @llvmquestioner sorry, meant to comment this on your main question. Anyway, I'll try and find it again. I needed it recently and it took me forever to find. For something that includes this much assumption-based boilerplate, you would think it would be easier to find.

Comment: I added `@EnableTransactionManagement`, but in log I can't see the word: `TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector `

Answer (score 0):

There is spring.factories in META-INF of spring-boot-autoconfigure-{whatever-is-ur-bootversion}.jar

Open spring.factories and have a look
EnableAutoConfiguaration annotation is equal to many comma separated configuration files. And specific configuration files are automatically loaded based on your starters.

You can open these files and evaluate.